# flutter_reactive_ble - how to check if device is connected before subscribing

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using this plugin to try to develop an app that uses a Bluetooth module.

GitHub https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/

I'm trying to modify what the example included in the source code, so that **onTap of the list of devices, would connect and subscribeToCharacteristic**.

but, it seems that the connectToDevice() method is declared as a stream,

and putting **"await"** before the method call won't really fit my criteria (on a device connected, then subscribeToCharacteristic)

how do I achieve this?

**what I currently have in device_list.dart**

```
(device) => ListTile(
    title: Text(device.name),
    subtitle: Text("${device.id}\nRSSI: ${device.rssi}"),
    leading: const BluetoothIcon(),
    onTap: () async {
        widget.stopScan();
        await widget.deviceConn.connect(device.id);
        //call to subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic);
    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble#establishing-connection explains how to establish a connection and listen to the connection state. Wouldn't that help you?

Answer (score 1):

`await` only works in case the method returns a future. You should listen to the stream and when the stream emits a the `connected` state you execute the subscribe call. For example:

```dart
_ble.connectToDevice(id: deviceId).listen(
      (update) {
        if(update.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected){
       // execute subscribe
        }
      },
```

Comment: hi @remonh87, after done with listening, and get the data how to stop listening? but stays connected without disconnecting?

Comment: yes when you stop listening to the connection stream the devices gets disconnected.

Comment: can i use subscribeStream?.cancel() to stop the listening?

Comment: im quite confuse on the usage of subscribe, in the example app, the app only use it straight from connect>subscribe>get response

but, what if i want to use it like connect > subscribe > un subscribe from 1 app page, then move to other page, subscribe back, all while remain the connection?

Comment: I would check https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/bc030414a540c92b00dc363891c8f1013eaf807e/example/lib/src/ble/ble_device_connector.dart#L45